# How to upload url image to s3 with boto3

Tags: python-3.x, image, http, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Given a url of an image i want to upload the image to s3 bucket with boto3. I have seen ways to do this using the requests module but since i am using lambda im wondering if i could do it with off the shelf functions like urllib.requests instead.

Comment: You can use same boto3 in lambda in python language, with input as a stream.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to use a Lambda function within AWS to upload a file to S3? If this is the case, requests can still be used - read this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/